# Creating shaded relief in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, contour, shaded-relief

How can I create shaded relief from contour lines (.shp format)?

I see Hillshade in ArcToolbox, but it asks for a raster file.

I have ArcGIS 10.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first need to create a raster layer from your vector contour layer.  You can use the Topo to Raster tool under the Spatial Analysis Tools>Interpolation toolbox (reference via vs 9.3.1 not sure if it is the same in 10).  Once you have your raster layer, then you can use the Hillshade tool.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But when I create raster with Topo to Raster, and then Hillshade tool, I get small resolution raster, and I need bigger resolution.

Comment: How can I get raster with better resolution?

Comment: @against http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About_environment_settings_for_raster_data

Comment: I still don't know what value I should write in Output cell size.

Comment: I need 5m resolution, but when I enter 5, it gives me error.

Comment: I just restarted ArcMap and I get it with 5m resolution! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -2):

contour to terrain then terrain to raster. More control over the output pixel size.